# Split text on a special character to several columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a query which is returning a text in on column that has several tags.
Number of tags is not fixed.
for example: @Description @start Date @End Date @Reference
I am trying to split the text on separate columns for each tag.

Regards,
Yousef

Comment: Have you tried searching for 'split string'?

Comment: @Aleksej, the OP wants to split it in columns, not in rows. That would at least involve a PIVOT operation after what is suggested in the doc you linked. But there might be some other ways.

Comment: How would you use the resulting query? Are you in a PLSQL or in SQL? Consider that a plain SQL query can not have a variable number of resulting columns

Comment: @Aleksej, I am using SQL. The output will be used in report generating.

Comment: You can not build a plain SQL query with a variable number of columns; you'd probably better try to solve the issue in the reporting part

Comment: @Aleksej I got this now:
with data as
(select 'Description @@Start Date @@Maturity @@Reference' as tags from dual)
select regexp_substr(tags,'[^@@]+',1,level) tags
from data
connect by regexp_substr(tags,'[^@@]+',1,level) is not null
This will give a result of one column with "TAGS" as header and a separate row for each tag.
What I need now is no move the rows to be separated columns.

Comment: @Yousef - Note that your query to separate the values (which is essentially correct) will need two more lines of code if you have more than one input string. Then the other question: changing the rows to column **can't be done** in plain SQL. It can be done with "dynamic SQL" (which is not plain SQL, despite the similar name), but it is much better to do it in your reporting application.